# Does the series converge/converge absolutely/diverge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^a\ln n}$$
>   $$a>0$$
>
> Does the series converge/converge absolutely/diverge ?

I tried to divide to cases and factor the series:

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^a\ln n}=\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n^a}\sum\frac{1}{\ln n}$

for $a \le 1$ the series $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n^a}$ converges (from Leibniz), and doesn't converge absolutely but $\sum\frac{1}{\ln n} $ diverges. So I guess factoring the series into two is not how to solve this.

Now trying the condensation test:

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{2^n(-1)^{2^n}}{{2^n}^a\ln 2^n} \Rightarrow 
\frac{2^{n(1-a)}}{\ln 2^n}$

If $a \ge 1$ it goes to infinity.

If $a \le 1$ it also goes to infinity.

I think I'm doing somthing wrong.

Any advice ?

Comment: This is an alternating series. Try out the Leibniz test-http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Comment: The condensation test is for monotonically non-increasing terms, not for alternating terms.

Comment: Right, so it does converge for all a. and converge absolutely for $a > 1$ and doesn't converge absolutely for $a \le1$.

Comment: The step where you factor the series is not valid. There is no rule that says that $$\sum_na_nb_n=\sum_na_n\sum_nb_n$$
You would only use the condensation test for the absolute convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) says that
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^a\log(n)}
$$
converges conditionally since $\frac1{n^a\log(n)}$ monotonically converges to $0$.

For absolute convergence, by comparison to
$$
\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac1{n^a}
$$
the series converges absolutely for $a\gt1$.

For $a=1$, the [integral test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) shows that the series diverges absolutely since
$$
\int_2^M\frac1{x\log(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\log(\log(M))-\log(\log(2))
$$
diverges as $M\to\infty$.

If you can't use the integral test, you can use the [condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) for $a=1$:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^n\frac1{2^n\log(2^n)}=\frac1{\log(2)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n
$$
diverges since the [harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29) diverges.

Since the series diverges for $a=1$, the comparison test with
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\log(n)}
$$
shows that the series diverges absolutely for $a<1$.

Comment: so it converge absolutely for any $a$?

Comment: @guynaa: no. The alternating series test only works for conditional convergence. I noticed the part of the question regarding absolute convergence and added a section on absolute convergence.

Comment: We can't use integrals yet. Can we use that comparison test for $ a \le 1$ ?

Comment: You can use comparison for $a\lt1$, but for $a=1$, you can use the condensation test.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note that your series should be $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^a \ln n}$$ since the logarithm function becomes zero at $n=1$. Let us consider the absolute valued series first,

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^a \ln n}$$

Note that,

$$\frac{1}{n^a \ln n}<\frac{1}{n^a}\mbox{ for }n\geq 3$$

Hence by the direct comparison test we have $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^a \ln n}$ converges when $a>1$. That is $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^a \ln n}$ absolutely converges when $a>1$.

Ir remains to show the case $a\leq 1$. I still haven't come with a method for that. :)

Comment: Can't you just compare it to 1/n for $a \le 1$?

Comment: Well the comparison test only works when all the terms of the series are positive. But in this case you have a alternating series. If you take the absolute valued seres, $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^a \ln n}$ then using the limit comparison test with $1/n$ is useless because $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ diverges and then we cannot imply anything about our original series.

Comment: Rather than using the above method, I now realize that this could be solved using the alternating series test. :)